# regex negation match

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have a pattern as follows in the logs:

```
| App: | -> which doesn't have the app information 
| App: Registration | -> which indicates that this is registration app.
```

I want to be able to find the `| App: |` ones from the log.

I tried following regexes but failed, so decided to ask here.

`/App: ^(.*) |?/g` and some others but failed.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `/| App: |/g`? Or `/| App: *|/g` in case of multiple spaces.

Comment: do you want to use this regex in `Java` or `C#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the vertical bar in Java.  On its own vertical bar is an operator in a regular expression.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
String test = "| App: | ABC";
String test2 = "| App: Registration |";
String match = "\\| App:.*\\|.*";
System.out.println(test.matches(match));
System.out.println(test2.matches(match));
```

Comment: Wellll... you also have to escape the backslash :) hahah, it's like a really bad prank that the Java folks are playing on you! See ProgrammersBlock's code example above.